# Assertion failure in -[KeychainItemWrapper writeToKeychain] method

Tags: ios, xcode, keychainitemwrapper

Received below error and my app crashes. Removed derived data still not success.

```
2016-11-16 17:57:33.285311 WCMH[59760:914565] [MC] Reading from private effective user settings.
2016-11-16 17:57:33.285 WCMH[59760:914454] *** Assertion failure in -[KeychainItemWrapper writeToKeychain], 

2016-11-16 17:57:33.286574 WCMH[59760:914580] [] nw_host_stats_add_src recv too small, received 24, expected 28
2016-11-16 17:57:33.287290 WCMH[59760:914580] [] nw_host_stats_add_src recv too small, received 24, expected 28
2016-11-16 17:57:33.289270 WCMH[59760:914580] [] nw_host_stats_add_src recv too small, received 24, expected 28
2016-11-16 17:57:33.290745 WCMH[59760:914580] [] nw_host_stats_add_src recv too small, received 24, expected 28
2016-11-16 17:57:33.290 WCMH[59760:914454] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: 'Couldn't add the Keychain Item.'
```

Comment: can you show the KeychainItemWrapper code, what you have written???

Comment: Its crashing in below code.

KeychainItemWrapper* keychain = [[KeychainItemWrapper alloc] initWithIdentifier:@"com.test.testApp" accessGroup:nil];
    [keychain setObject:(__bridge id)kSecAttrAccessibleWhenUnlocked forKey:(__bridge id)kSecAttrAccessible];

Comment: Where is your code?